# Can't fetch binance futures data from ccxt

Tags: binance, binance-api-client, ccxt

I need to fetch funding rate history data from binance, but it only shows spot markets even when I type:

```
binance = ccxt.binance({'option': {'defaultType': 'future'}})

binance.fetch_markets()
```

How is it possible to fix?

Comment: it's `options` not `option`, you can also use `binanceusdm` instead of `binance`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.binance()

exchange.options = {'defaultType': 'future',
                    'adjustForTimeDifference': True}

symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
funding = exchange.fetchFundingRate(symbol)
print(funding)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we fetch exchange information using ccxt

Replace API KEY AND SECRET WITH YOURS

```
import ccxt from 'ccxt';

const exchangeClass = ccxt['binanceusdm'];
    const exchange = new exchangeClass({
        'apiKey': "apiKey",
        'secret': "secret",
        'options': {
            'defaultType': 'future',
        }
    });
    // console.log(symbol, type, side, quantity,  price,  param ,"spam" )
    
    exchange.setSandboxMode(false)
    
    //get exchange information
    const exchangeInfo = await exchange.fetchMarkets();
```